# Non-widescreen tablet + widescreen display

Tags: graphics, peripherals, widescreen, graphics-tablet

Most of the screens are 16:9 now, most of the graphics tablets are not.

How does an **A5 tablet** (like Pentagram Designer, for instance) interact with a **wide screen display**? Do I get dead zones at screen edges, or at tablet edges, or perhaps different resolution horizontally and vertically (which would be bad)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the behaviour can be customised in most drivers (either to fit the whole screen or a portion of it, optionally preserving aspect ratio.

**Pentagram** Designer:

[image]

**Wacom** Pen&Touch:

[image]

Translation:

- Screen area:

  - All screens
  - Screen [1]
  - Area [Set]
- Scaling:

  - [ ] Enforce proportions
- Tablet area:

  - Full
  - Area [Set]